# If i download Tor will i keep my other browsers and be able to use them still?

Tags: browsers

I just wanna know if it will make it my default browser and get rid of my other ones or what

Comment: It won't be made your "default" browser, it actually tries to stop this from happening and will resist attempts to make it such. It's not "installed", it's more like a portable app.

Comment: ok thanks, so its just another thing i can open up whenever i want but i can continue to use like Chrome how i do everyday?

Comment: Yes, you can still use other browsers like normal.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you will be able to use your browsers: it's *just* another browser on your system. And - regardless of many others - it's installer does not set it as a default totally, so you are free to use it *only the times you're launching it explicitly*

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You will have added an additional browser, but it will not remove or otherwise affect your current browsers in any way.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, when you extract/install tor it installs into a separate directory, it will never ask to become your default browser.